# How to test redux saga using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-saga

I have a saga function that I am trying to test using jest and enzyme but I am getting an error. This is my first time testing saga file so I do not have an idea why I am getting the error even though expected and receive value are the same saga file is below:

```
export const getToken = (state) => state.dextaAuth.token;

export function* setPost(action) {
  try {
    const token = yield select(getToken);
    const data = yield call(
      dextaApiService.post,
      "/api/savedAdvices",
      action.payload,
      token
    );
    yield put(
      openNotification({
        messageType: MessageBarType.success,
        message: "Advice saved successfully",
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(
      openNotification({
        messageType: MessageBarType.error,
        message: `Notification: ${err.message}`,
      })
    );
  }
}

export function* savedAdvicesaga() {
  yield takeLatest(POST_SAVED_ADVICE, setPost);
  yield takeLatest(FETCH_SAVED_ADVICE, fetchSavedAsviceAsync);
}
```

This the test case I have written:

```
describe("savedAdviceSaga", () => {
  const genObject = savedAdvicesaga();
  describe("setpost", () => {
    it("should check for post ", async () => {
      const apiResponse = jest
        .spyOn(dextaApiService, "post")
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());

      const dispatched = [];
      const action: types.SavedAdviceActionType = {
        type: types.POST_SAVED_ADVICE,
        payload: {
          Title: "test",
          Description: "test dec",
        },
      };
      const iterator = setPost(action);
      const effect = iterator.next().value;
      const expected = select(getToken);
      const result = await runSaga(
        {
          dispatch: (action) => dispatched.push(action),
        },
        setPost,
        action
      );
      expect(effect).toContainEqual(expected);
      expect(apiResponse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

This the error I am getting in the console:

```
expect(received).toContainEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected value:  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "combinator": false, "payload": {"args": [], 
    "selector": [Function anonymous]}, "type": "SELECT"}
Received object: {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "combinator": false, "payload": {"args": [], "selector": 
     [Function anonymous]}, "type": "SELECT"}

   27 |         dispatch: (action) => dispatched.push(action),
   28 |       }, setPost, action);
 > 29 |       expect(effect).toContainEqual(expected)
      |                      ^
   30 |       expect(apiResponse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
   31 |
   32 |     })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [Testing the full Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing#testing-the-full-saga) test strategy. Don't need to check each step of the saga.

> run the whole saga and assert that the expected effects have occurred.

[runSaga(options, saga, ...args)](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#runsagaoptions-saga-args) accept `getState()` option, so that you provide a mocked state. The `getToken` selector will use it.

E.g.

`saga.ts`:

```
import { call, put, select, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { dextaApiService } from './dextaApiService';

export const MessageBarType = {
  success: 'success',
  error: 'error',
};

export function openNotification({ messageType, message }) {
  return { type: messageType, payload: message };
}

export const getToken = (state) => state.dextaAuth.token;

export function* setPost(action) {
  try {
    const token = yield select(getToken);
    const data = yield call(dextaApiService.post, '/api/savedAdvices', action.payload, token);
    yield put(
      openNotification({
        messageType: MessageBarType.success,
        message: 'Advice saved successfully',
      }),
    );
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(
      openNotification({
        messageType: MessageBarType.error,
        message: `Notification: ${err.message}`,
      }),
    );
  }
}

export function* savedAdvicesaga() {
  yield takeLatest('POST_SAVED_ADVICE', setPost);
}
```

`dextaApiService.ts`:

```
export const dextaApiService = {
  async post(path, payload, token) {
    return 'real implementation';
  },
};
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { setPost } from './saga';
import { dextaApiService } from './dextaApiService';
import { runSaga } from 'redux-saga';
import { Action } from 'redux';

describe('67444295', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const dispatched: Action[] = [];
    const postSpy = jest.spyOn(dextaApiService, 'post').mockResolvedValueOnce('mocked response');
    const actual = await runSaga(
      {
        dispatch: (action: Action) => dispatched.push(action),
        getState: () => ({ dextaAuth: { token: 'abc123' } }),
      },
      setPost,
      { payload: 'mocked payload' },
    ).toPromise();
    expect(postSpy).toBeCalledWith('/api/savedAdvices', 'mocked payload', 'abc123');
    expect(dispatched).toEqual([{ type: 'success', payload: 'Advice saved successfully' }]);
    postSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/67444295/saga.test.ts
  67444295
    ✓ should pass (5 ms)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |   85.71 |        0 |      60 |      80 |                   
 dextaApiService.ts |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3                 
 saga.ts            |   89.47 |        0 |      75 |   84.62 | 26,36             
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.567 s
```